# Showing that there is a real $a$ such that $\frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{\sin(e^a)}{a^2 + 1}$ for all real $x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry

> How do we show that there exists $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, for which every $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$\frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{\sin(e^a)}{a^2 + 1}$$
>
> holds true?

This ended up being rather complicated. There was a hint stating that there would be no need for any derivatives here.

Comment: it holds if  $x=a${}{}{}{[{}{[

Comment: The function $\frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1}$ is continuous and bounded, so there exists such a number.

Comment: Note that as $|a| \to \infty$ the right hand side goes to zero. Hence there is a maximiser $a$.

Comment: @Dzoooks: That is necessary but not sufficient. $\operatorname{atan}$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use *Weierstraß' theorem*:

This function is continuous and $\;|\sin(\mathrm e^x)|\le 1$, $\;1+x^2\ge 1$, so $\;\Biggl|\dfrac{\sin(\mathrm e^x)}{x^2 + 1}\Biggr|\le 1, \: \cdots$

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: I just used that to find an upper bound for a fraction of positive numbers, you may either find an upper bound for the numerator or a positive lower bound for the denominator, or both. Ids it clear with these details? As to Weierstraß' theorem, it is none other than the extreme values theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = \frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1}$
Take $M = \max_{x \in [-10,10]} f(x)$.

$\frac{\sin(e^x)}{x^2+1}\to_{|x| \to \infty} 0$, hence $ \exists N s.t. \forall |x|>N$ we have $|f(x)| \leq M$.
Then since $[-N,N]$ is bounded and $f$ is cts, we can take $a$ to be the arg max of $f$ over this range. (Extreme Value Theorem)

Comment: If $M$ is the arg max then shouldn't the inequality be $|f(x)|\le |f(M)|$? Also how did you know a priori that the values of $M$ would be in $[-10,10]$?

Comment: it just ensures that the max lies in $[-N,N]$, its totally arbitrary. $M$ should be max, edited.